# How to know if there's a value inside an array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have this array of object:

```
[Object, Object]
 0: Object
    {
     date: ""
     number: undefined
    }
 1: Object
     {
      date: ""
      number: undefined
     }
```

It always said required if that value is not empty. Maybe someone can help me with much more knowledgeable about this.

**Here's my code:**

```
$(function(){

 var len = $('#groupContainer > div').length;
 var arr = [];

 for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

    var number = $('#number_' + [i + 1]);
    var date = $('#date_' + [i + 1]);

    console.log(number)

    var a = number.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });

    var b = date.map(function(){
        return this.value;
    });

    var newObj = {number: a[0], date: b[0]}
    arr.push(newObj);
 }

 for(var c = 0; c < arr.length; c++)
 {
    var count = c + 1;
    var message ="";

    for(var d in arr[c])
    {
        if(arr[c].hasOwnProperty(d))
        {       
            if(arr[c][d] == "")
            {
                message = d + ' is required!';
            }
            message += message + "\n";
        }
    }
    alert('Group: ' + count + ' ' + message + '\n');
  }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aldrin27/z4yfohao/10/)**

Comment: what are you trying to do? i'm missing something

Comment: I'm trying to find if the value inside an array of object is null or empty. If not empty it will not show the alertbox.

Comment: you need to check the entire object? or a specific property?

Comment: so you would consider this as null object `{name:''}` but this as not null `{name:'abc'}`, am i right?

Comment: what's the expected result for this object `{name:'abc', id: null}` ?

Comment: The expected result is in the alertbox. If there are empty value inside the object it will show the the alertbox some fields is required else success.

Comment: @JossefHarush A `null` or `undefined` value shouldn't be possible unless the selector doesn't match the field. An `<input>` element's `value` can't be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check on emptiness appears to work correctly. Both fields in "Group 1" have a value and its message doesn't mention either as "required."

Though, you have an issue with how the `message` is being built, reporting a single property at least twice:

```
"Group: 2 date is required!date is required!"
```

This is due to these modifications of `message`:

```
if(arr[c][d] == "")
{
    message = d + ' is required!';
}
message += message + "\n";
```

The first line modifying the `message`, by using the assignment operator (`=`), will discard any previous value that `message` may have held.

```
var message = "something previous"

message = 'property' + ' is required!';

console.log(message); // "property is required!"
```

The other line then duplicates the contents of `message`, appending it to itself:

```
// same as `message = message + message + "\n";`
message += message + "\n";

console.log(message); // "property is required!property is required!\n"
```

How you could revise this is to modify `message` only when an empty field is found and concatenate onto the previous value with what's being added.

```
if(arr[c][d] == "")
{
    message += d + ' is required!\n';
    //      ^ concatenate onto the previous `message` value
    //        including the `\n` here
}
// remove the other modification
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b60981ku/

Comment: What if i don't want to show alertbox if not empty? But rather return true. And move to the next process?

Comment: @aldrin27 You can test if `message` is still empty after the loop -- `if (message) { alert(...); }`. Or, use another variable with `message` and `count`, such as `var anyEmpty = false;`, that you only set to `true` when an empty field is found, and test based on it -- `if (anyEmpty) { alert(...); }`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the variable is null or empty by,

```
arr[c][d] == null || arr[c][d].length <= 0
```

If I am not mistaken what you're trying to achieve..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dqge2hzh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

## Use a Custom validation

From what i understand after our small comment dialog, you should implement a custom validation like the one in the following function

```
function isObjectNullOrEmpty(obj) {
    if (!obj) {
        return true;
    }

    var requiredKeys = ['name'];
    for (var i in requiredKeys) {
        var key = requiredKeys[i];
        var value = obj[key];
        if (value === undefined || value === null) {
            return true;
        }

        if ((typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String) && !value.trim()) {
            return true
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

## http://jsfiddle.net/nknaftq3/

```
$(function () {

    var object1 = {
        name: ''
    };
    alert(JSON.stringify(object1) + ' \n\nresult : ' + isObjectNullOrEmpty(object1));

    
    var object2 = {
        name: 'asd'
    };
    alert(JSON.stringify(object2) + ' \n\nresult : ' + isObjectNullOrEmpty(object2));

});
```